# Changing views frame origin causes it to bounce back into place

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard-events

I am attempting, when the keyboard appears, to shift the view up. This works on two views, but on the third the same code causing the view to seemingly move down a certain amount, then move back into the exact place it started, or so the animation seems. Debugging, I see nowhere else the self.view.frame is getting set but this method. In addition, the offsets look right, as if the view should move up like the other views have. See the keyboardWillShow method below.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    if self.origFrame == nil{
        self.origFrame = self.view.frame
    }
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue(){
        var testRect = self.view.frame
        testRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
        if !testRect.contains(loginBtn!.frame.origin){
            let bottomSpace = self.view.frame.size.height - loginBtn.frame.origin.y - loginBtn.frame.size.height
            let keyboardOverlap = keyboardSize.height - bottomSpace
            let newY = self.origFrame!.origin.y - keyboardOverlap
            self.view.frame.origin.y = newY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using auto-layout? It's typically bad practice to change the frames of views when using auto-layout

Comment: @LukePatterson I use constraints to layout my views. What would be the best way to move the view when the keyboard appears in that case?

Comment: Steven, how about you change the constraints programmatically when the keyboard shows/hides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done in the past

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    let point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: textView.frame.origin.x - 8, y: textView.frame.origin.y - 100)
    scrollView.contentOffset = point
}
```

This moves the view up based on the position of textview the user tapped on. 8 and 100 pixels just happened to be good ranges for my specific purpose.

Alternatively, instead of moving the frames, you could programmatically adjust your constraints.